# Does Heaven Sent have more references to this work than just the obvious plot point?

Tags: doctor-who

A key plot point of *Heaven Sent* is

> the fairy tale, [The Shepherd Boy](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_Household_Tales,_Volume_2/The_Shepherd_Boy), which gives the Doctor the idea to chip away at the azbantium wall over billions of years.

My question is, was the episode designed to include other references to this, such that maybe the viewers could even figure out the resolution before the Doctor does? In addition to sharing the "three questions" element, I've noticed parallels between the questions from the aforementioned work...

> 1. How many drops of water are there in the ocean?
>
>  2. How many stars are there in the sky?
>
>  3. How many seconds of time are there in eternity? (which the boy answers by describing the bird who weathers away a mountain with its beak)

...and the clues that the Doctor finds throughout the episode, in order:

> 1. Countless skulls in the ocean.
>
>  2. The positions of the stars.
>
>  3. The "BIRD" plot point, of course.

Are these similarities intentional, or am I doing the impossible and overthinking Steven Moffat's writing?

Comment: At first, I thought of "Groundhog Day". Living the same day over and over again...

Comment: I think we're going to have to wait to see if Moffat says something in an interview to clarify this question. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: After I watched the ep for the first time, I thought the "BIRD" referred to the phoenix that rises from its own ashes. That that was the hint he gave to himself. Didn't make the connection to the story about the mountain until after reading the myriad of questions here!

Comment: @MrLister Rewatch it, starting from the part where he punches the wall for the first time. If you can listen past the epic score (and I don't blame you if you can't), he's reciting the story as he punches. Hence the reference to everyone's favorite German storytellers who happen to be excellent darts players.

Comment: @MrLister In fact, the rather slow progress through the story is part of how the script (and the director) conveys how very long it's going to take The Doctor to get through the wall. The jump from 7k to 12k years doesn't gain him even one more word. It's only as the tunnel gets longer, making the Veil take longer to reach him, that he gets any further in the story.